# What is the difference between these 2 ways of installing Theano on Windows?

Tags: python, theano

I want to install Theano on my windows 8.1 x64 machine. I already have anaconda (latest 64 bit) with python 2.7.x version.

I have two options of installing:

```
  # Option 1 : from pip 
  pip install Theano
```

And

```
  # Option 2 : Bleeding edge from git
  pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

Can someone let me know the major differences between two and which one is suggested to install?

Comment: This information isn't a good fit for the knowledge-base format: It's going out-of-date as soon as it's created (and will be *entirely* outdated the moment there's a new release published to pip).

Comment: ...actually, perhaps not so much -- I apparently misread intent. (Perhaps this is a question about what "bleeding edge" means, then? It has a general meaning in software not specific to Theano).

Comment: The first installs the version in the pypi repo https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Theano, which currently is at version 0.8.2, the second installs directly from the github repo which currently is at version 0.9 https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/setup.py.  It's open source code, so look at the code, git commits and/or issues to decide which you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using below command, you might end up installing an older version of Theano i.e. all missing updates etc.

```
pip install Theano
```

While using command for [bleeding edge version](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions) installation, you might get an updated (latest developer) version of Theano.

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

Comment: If the OP didn't already know this, they wouldn't have had the "bleeding edge" comment in their question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not sure... just answered the question. :)

Comment: Thanks for answer @Manoj Kumar, so can I go ahead and install from the git ?

Comment: @MadhuSareen, you can, though you risk getting bugs from running code that hasn't seen production use and is prone to change with little notice -- being so new as to have risks from same is why something that's "bleeding edge" is named thusly. (Contrast to "cutting-edge" meaning latest-and-greatest; "bleeding-edge" is even newer and less tested than that).

Comment: @MadhuSareen However people using the latest releases and reporting bugs to the devs is what keeps software like this continuously developing!

Answer (score 0):

this line is for installing theano:

```
pip install Theano
```

the other command is for updating already installed theano:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```